# pic16f877a problems

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, circuit-design

I'm pretty new to the pic. 
I've made a really long circuit on proteus, ran my program, things worked out great.
I then moved on to the breadboard, nothing really worked.

I made another prpgram that was much simpler. All the registers were set to output and low except for 2 pins which were set to high.

I transferred the circuit to the breadboard and tested the pins that were set to high with an led. They weren't exactly high, I noticed some flickering. Other than that, all the outputs gave the same result even though they were set to low.

The micrcontroller (along with the voltage regulator) itself also overheated within half a minute, to the point that it's really hot to the touch.

5v went to pin 1, pin 11, and pin 32.
Gnd went to pin 12, and pin 31.
Oscillator went to pin 13, and pin 14
Nothing else connected other than a single led. (and the oscillator circuit)

Did I do something wrong?

EDIT
Here are the pics of my breadboard configuration

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: If the micro-controller and regulator got hot you surely did something wrong. Could you post a pciture?

Comment: You did have a resistor in series with that LED didn't you ... ?

Comment: How about power supply decoupling capacitors? A circuit and a picture is minimum to properly help.

Comment: By oscillator circuit, you mean the two caps connected to the crystal and also to ground, right?

Comment: For the led, yes, I did have a resistor. I used a jumper wite before the resistor to switch it from pin to pin. @brianrho yes, that's the one. I used two 22pf caps and and an 8MHz crystal.

Comment: I can't post a picture right now as I'm about to go to school. I have this variable power supply (bought it before) that has 4.5v and 6 v so I made a module that had a switch, filter, and lm7805 with no heatsink. I figured that the circuit wouldn't really draw much current and 6 to 5 volts wasn't really that large. I tested this circuit and the output really works well at a stable 5v.

Comment: Yep, the crystal IS connected to OSC1 and OSC2 via the jumper wires. The pic16f877a doesn't have an internal oscillator, I bought this microcontroller thinking that it did have one but after some troubles, I read that it didn't really have one.

Comment: Your crystal should be located right next to the OSC1 and OSC2 pins. But why are you using a crystal at all? Just to get up and running, you should use the internal RC oscillator mode. See section 14.2.3 in the datasheet.  Better yet, switch to the [PIC16F1789](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001675C.pdf) which has a 32 MHz internal precision (calibrated to 1%) oscillator.

Comment: I have been thinking of buying another pic that really has an internal oscillator but I just can't get over this pic until I get to know what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry about the repeated comment, they don't allow comments to be edited here after five  minutes and I wanted to add info about the PIC16F1789.  It has a precision internal oscillator, while the PICF877A does have an internal RC oscillator but it is not calibrated.

Comment: It's fine. I actually appreciated the suggestion. I'll keep an eye out for that microcontroller.

Comment: The PIC16F1789 appears to be a much newer part; it's datasheet is dated 2013 and the PIC16F877A's datasheet is dated 2001.  PIC16F1789 is also half the price of the PIC16F877A.

Comment: You might wangt to attach the firmware source, including the configuration bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use another 16F877. Revise your connections against the datasheet for proper pin selections. A proper schematic of your actual circuit wiring will certainly help to spot any incongruencies. The LED diode load should be serialy connected to a resistor.
Try verifying the points above. You could be dealing with a shorted unit. The heat is a tell-a-tale sign. Three things: Internal short, incorrect load wiring or incorrect chip wiring. Also, check polarities.

Comment: Agree. Try another IC. OP may have reversed the power and damaged the IC, or touched the MCU pins without proper precaution and caused ESD damage. ESD damage will result in high leakage, high power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pretty long leads for an oscillator, even at a relatively slow 8 MHz.  Possibly the extra parasitics on those leads are causing an oscillator fault, which could put the PIC in an indeterminate or unstable state and result in odd output behavior and increased power consumption (I've done this accidentally when prototyping myself, but not on an 877; the PIC I was using had an option to use an internal oscillator and after switching to that the problem abruptly went away).

I'd double-check the value and type of the power supply bypass caps, too.  The 877 may be old enough to be more robust, but I know (again, from personal experience) the dsPICs are very particular about the bypass capacitors.

Of course appliedpr may be correct that your chip is just defective, but these are good things to keep in mind when troubleshooting and might be easier for you to check if you don't have a spare 877 on hand yet.

Comment: I almost forgot about this post. I used another PIC chip, everything's fine now.